# Button not responding to selector

Tags: ios

**UPDATED FOR COMMENTS**

I am trying to make this code work, but whenever I press the "nextButton", the program ends and I cannot figure out what went wrong. Can you please look at my code and figure out if anything is wrong.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

Player1.placeholder = @"Player 1";
Player2.placeholder = @"Player 2";
Notes1.placeholder = @"Notes";
Notes2.placeholder = @"Notes";

[nextButton setAction:@selector(nextButtonPressed:)];

}

-(IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {

if ([self.delegateP respondsToSelector: @selector(addPlayerViewController:didFinishEnteringPlayer1:didFinishEneteringPlayer2:)]) {

    [self.delegateP addPlayerViewController:self didFinishEnteringPlayer1:Player1.text didFinishEneteringPlayer2:Player2.text];

    NSLog(@"Works");

 }

[self performSelector:@selector(nextButtonPressed:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];

}
```

I also have another question to do with this code. To pass information through different view controllers using delegates, do you have to use a button or a bar button item?

The error that is displaying:

> > -[UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate nextButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash and error message.

Comment: Is your `nextButtonPressed` method being called? Why do you both present and push the view controller? Just do one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a symbolic breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions and see if that gives you your crash line numbers and error messages again.

The code you posted for setting up the target/action on your bar button item looks correct.

#### Edit: Disregard this part about changing the selector.

(I'm leaving it for continuity, but ignore it.)

> One thing you might try is changing the selector to
>   `:@selector(nextButtonPressed:)` (Colon added)
>
> And then adding the button as a parameter to your action method:
>
> ```
> -(IBAction) nextButtonPressed: (UIButton *) sender
> ```
>
> Action methods should work with or without the sender parameter, but
>   it's worth trying.

(Also you should add the IBAction keyword for clarity even if you're not hooking up the action in IB.)

### EDIT: rmaddy pointed out that your code is trying to both modally present and push the same view controller. Don't do that. Do one thing or the other.

You should use either

```
 [self presentModalViewController:gameDetails animated:YES];
```

(To present it as a modal)

or

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController: gameDetails animated:YES];
```

(To push it onto the navigation stack.

But not both. Doing both is almost certainly the cause of your crash.

Comment: The OP's code for setting up the selector and the current method are fine. No need to change anything. Most likely the crash is due to both presenting and pushing the same view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy: Oh dear, I didn't notice that. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

First you can´t put both lines:

```
[self presentModalViewController:gameDetails animated:YES];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController: gameDetails animated:YES];
```

Second go to your viewController PlayersViewController and click in storyboard click on editor (top menú XCode) Embed In > Navigation Controller now you with your code change the next lines:

```
-(void) nextButtonPressed {
NSLog(@"Hi my friend");
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE" sender:@"hi"];}
```

And create new function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
    [vc setMyObjectHere:sender];
}}
```

The ViewController "YourViewController.h :

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *MyObjectHere;
@end
```

Comment: Why do you assume there are storyboards and segues involved? Very little of this answer is relevant to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy I asume all because he change code all times.